# Bug in Swift - score increment - Tic Tac Toe game

Tags: swift

Having issues with my Tic Tac Toe game. With my game, once a win condition is met (or draw), the code is supposed to disable all of the x or O buttons being clicked, display a message and increment the player 1, 2 or draw score by 1.

Everything is working apart from the fact that if I continue to click any button in the X/O grid after the game is over, the score for the winner continues to increment, and I can't resolve this.

This is my code. Apologies, I am rather new to this.

```
var gameState = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
var p1Score = 0
var p2Score = 0
var drawScore = 0
var scoreHistory = ""
var gameIsActive = true

@IBAction func action(_ sender: AnyObject)
{
    if (gameState[sender.tag-1] == 0 && gameIsActive == true)
    {
        gameState[sender.tag-1] = activePlayer

        if (activePlayer == 1)
        {
            sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "Cross.png"), for: UIControlState())
            activePlayer = 2
        }
        else
        {
            sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "Nought.png"), for: UIControlState())
            activePlayer = 1
        }
    }
    //Rules to determine a Draw
    gameIsActive = false

    for i in gameState
    {
        if i == 0
        {
            gameIsActive = true
            break
        }
    }

    if gameIsActive == false
    {
        displayResult.text = "It was a Tie"
        displayResult.isHidden = false
        resetGame.isHidden = false
        drawScore = drawScore + 1
        drawCount.text = ""+"\(drawScore)"
        resultHistory.text! += scoreHistory + "It was a Draw" + "\n"
    }
for combination in winningCombinations //Win combination checks
    {
        if gameState[combination[0]] != 0 && gameState[combination[0]] == gameState[combination[1]] && gameState[combination[1]] == gameState[combination[2]]
        {
            gameIsActive = false // Game no longer playable

            if gameState[combination[1]] == 1 {
                //Player 1 has won and score is updated
                displayResult.text = "Player 1 has won"
                p1Score = p1Score + 1                                             //score increments on win
                player1Score.text = "" + "\(p1Score)"                       //score added to Score Label
                resultHistory.text! +=  scoreHistory + "" + "\n" //match outcome added to history

            }
            else
            {
                //Player 2 has won and score is updated
                displayResult.text = "Player 2 has won"
                p2Score = p2Score + 1                                             //score increments on win
                player2Score.text = "" + "\(p2Score)"                       //score added to Score Label
                resultHistory.text! +=  scoreHistory + "" + "\n" //match outcome added to history

            }
            displayResult.isHidden = false                                            //Winner is shown on screen
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Emphasis on minimal.

Comment: Links to your code are frowned upon here. It's much better to (1) strip your code down to something replicable, (2) then copy and paste it into your question. From the sounds of it, it's pretty easy for someone not "so new" to see the issue. But without code we're probably more handicapped than you are. The easy part of MCVE is giving us code *in the question* that helps us replicate your issue.

Comment: Sorry. I'm wondering if this helps.

Comment: `gameIsActive == false` :-(

Comment: Sorry, not sure how to fix that? If i set it to true, the game will just continue, no? I changed gameisActive to true, and now the game states it's a draw right away - still no luck with the score not updating. I've added more of my code

Answer (score 0):

You want to immediately exit your `action` function if the user clicks on a button that is already an `X` or an `O` or if `gameIsActive == false` because there is nothing to do in those cases.  You can fix your program by adding two `guard` statements at the top:

```
@IBAction func action(_ sender: AnyObject)
{
    guard gamesState[sender.tag-1] == 0 else { return }
    guard gameIsActive else { return }

    gameState[sender.tag-1] = activePlayer

    if activePlayer == 1
    {
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "Cross.png"), for: UIControlState())
        activePlayer = 2
    }
    else
    {
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "Nought.png"), for: UIControlState())
        activePlayer = 1
    }
```

Also, your logic for determining a draw is flawed.  If the winner wins on the last move, your code will count it as a draw because the board is filled.  You should check for a win condition first, then if the game is still active because no one has won check for the draw condition.

```
// After checking for winning combinations

if gameIsActive {
    //Rules to determine a Draw
    gameIsActive = false

    for i in gameState
    {
        if i == 0
        {
            gameIsActive = true
            break
        }
    }

    if !gameIsActive
    {
        displayResult.text = "It was a Tie"
        displayResult.isHidden = false
        resetGame.isHidden = false
        drawScore = drawScore + 1
        drawCount.text = ""+"\(drawScore)"
        resultHistory.text! += scoreHistory + "It was a Draw" + "\n"
    }
}
```

Although you could check for a draw with:

```
if gameIsActive && !gameState.contains(0) {
    // It's a draw
    gameIsActive = false

    displayResult.text = "It was a Tie"
    ...
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  If my answer is not clear, post a comment.  If it solved your issue, click on the checkmark to the left of it to turn it green. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235